# Using both english and greek language in Rmarkdown with pdf output creates conflicts

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdflatex, xelatex

Hello I am trying to print a report from Rmarkdown in pdf using both greek and english language, I tried this code

````
---
output: 
bookdown::pdf_document2:
toc: true
number_sections: true
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{hyperref}
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
- \usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
- \newcommand{\en}[1]{{\selectlanguage{english}#1}}
- \newcommand{\gr}[1]{{\selectlanguage{greek}#1}}
---
---
title: \gr{Δοκιμαστικό}
subtitle: \en{Company  S.A.}
---
```{r warning=FALSE, include=FALSE}
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
```
---
date: "_`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`_"
---
---
abstract: 
---
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsection{subsection}
````

It gives me this error:

```
Try other LaTeX engines instead (e.g., xelatex) if you are using pdflatex. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-unicode.html
Error: LaTeX failed to compile file.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See file.log for more info.
In addition: Warning message:
In has_crop_tools() : 
Tool(s) not installed or not in PATH: ghostcript
-> As a result, figure cropping will be disabled.
Execution halted
```

But when I replace Δοκιμαστικό with Dokimastiko it prints me
[image]

and when i used this code

````
---
output:
   pdf_document:
     latex_engine: xelatex
toc: true
number_sections: true
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{hyperref}
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
- \usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
- \newcommand{\en}[1]{{\selectlanguage{english}#1}}
- \newcommand{\gr}[1]{{\selectlanguage{greek}#1}}
---
---
title: \gr{Δοκιμαστικό}
subtitle: \en{Company  S.A.}
---
```{r warning=FALSE, include=FALSE}
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
```
---
date: "_`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`_"
---
````

It gives me this
[image]

Well this is not a solution for my case and also automated date is not printed right, is there any other way to use both greek and english language without conflicts?

Comment: How do you want the date? In greek or english?

Comment: The first example does not work because `bookdown::pdf_document2:` in not indented correctly

Comment: In the second example you need to choose a font that contains all the glyphs you want to show. For example I have TeX Gyre Heros installed, so I can use  `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}`.

Comment: greek i replaced Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English") with Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE","Greek") and it gives me this on date 07 `ΙΫέïὸ, 2021. The problem is that i cannot write any greek sentence on the document.

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
l.78 \setmainfont
                 {TeX Gyre Heros}

Comment: Can you check if https://rstudio.cloud/project/2490816 is the output you want?

Comment: I tried my code in  rstudio.cloud/project/2490816  and greek sentences work just fine. I do not know why in my R code fails.

Comment: Might be a version problem. Maybe your your pandoc/tex/rmarkdown version is outdated ...

Comment: Sorry, no translations available for el_GR (nor el); falling back to English.
    Make sure that you have the package "texlive-msg-translations" installed.
    (If you'd like to help translate the installer's messages, please see
    http://tug.org/texlive/doc.html#install-tl-xlate for information.) This is the error with full greek language that rstudio.cloud prints but mine does not.

Comment: the babel greek package needs to be installed.

Comment: (all such problems can be avoided by using a full texlive installation -- can be done with `tlmgr install scheme-full`)

Comment: how do i use a full texlive installation?

Comment: Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘texlive-msg-translations’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages